# Spindle speed of classic Cable Porter 100-M router?

Tags: woodworking, powertools, routers

I'm trying to calculate proper feed rates for my Cable Porter 100-M router which I have mounted on a 3-axis CNC machine. The spindle speed is not listed in the original [user manual](http://vintagemachinery.org/pubs/detail.aspx?id=22348).

[image]

1. Does anyone know what would be a reasonable spindle RPM to use in my feed rate calculator? (I'm machining timber.)
2. As a sanity check, what would you expect to be a reasonable feed rate for a 6.35 mm / 1/4" straight cutter on pine (softwood) and teak (hardwood) with, say, a 3 mm cutting depth.

Many thanks.

Comment: Is it listed on the plate?  It's probably 10,000 rpm or so.

Comment: No, it's not on the plate. Thanks.

Comment: What a refreshing owners manual: `1) Tighten the bit, if the shaft is too small use the proper adapter. 2) Make sure the tool is grounded. 3) Use it.` 10 pages covers 2 tools, including service center locations and exploded drawings of both tools. 10 pages barely covers all the legal "we told you that you could get hurt" mumbo-jumbo that prefaces _every_ owner's manual printed in the last 30 years...

Comment: @FreeMan. They were precious times. I thought readers would like the manual.

Comment: I did indeed enjoy reading something that didn't insult my intelligence. Thanks for the link!

Comment: I have one very very similar - I will get my son to look tomorrow as it is at his place and see if it mentions its speed...

Comment: I want to say 10-12k I have one actually 4-5 routers and the early ones were both smaller only 6 amps verses today’s 9-11 amps and higher speeds. Still carbide tooling will pay for itself even with soft wood. I would get some scrap and program both directions of cut and start with a guess that it is 10000rpm and increase your feed rate until you get chatter, one shop I managed had a radial arm router. Figuring out speeds and feeds With different plastic densities that’s how they built the speed profiles for cutting using a fixed speed find the sweet spot then the next speed and repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the last page (page 17?) of the manual that is attached, the Model 100 Router runs at 22,000 RPM.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Typical portable router speed is 22-24,000 RPM, which is what the bits are designed around. Variable speed versions will be adjustable down to around 8,000RPM, but you have to be careful about the bits you use.

Feed rate is WAY more complicated, because it involves the hardness of the wood and its likelihood to burn. It's been way too long for me to remember even where to find info on calculating that.

Comment: I agree the material density , speed rpm feed rate and diameter of the cutter all come into play.